# Как правильно написать "б/ушный"?

Tags: орфография

"Б/у" - общепринятое сокращение выражения "бывший в употреблении". А в просторечии о бывшей в употреблении вещи говорят, что она "бэушная" (написала так, как слышится). А как правильно записать это слово? Б/ушный? Б/Ушный? Бэушный? Понимаю, что это просторечная форма, но иногда (даже элементарно для интернет-общения) она нужна.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, так и надо (бэушная). Буква "бэ" и буква "у" употреблены в соответствии с их формальными названиями. Аналогично образовано широко употребляемое слово "эсэсовец" (тоже производное от аббревиатуры) и так же я бы записал слово "эсэмэска".

Answer (score 0):

Подобного рода "проблемы" грамматикой не рассматриваются. Это не просторечная форма, такого слова просто нет, поэтому пишите, как хотите. Главное, чтоб вас поняли.

Comment: В РОС это слово есть. См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E1%FD%F3%F8%ED%FB%E9

Comment: Правило склонения аббревиатур и словообразований от них с суффиксами (по названиям букв) нашлось в акад. справочнике под ред. Лопатина, параграф 204 (там есть и аналогичные примеры):
http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=95